# Django knockout model ko_json doesn't return proper field value defined in knockout_fields

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have django model instance and method `knockout_fields` (defined within it), which used to convert object to json by `knockout_modeler.ko.ko_json` method.

```
class OtherModel:
    somefield = '11'

class MyModel:
    field1 = ...
    # to make it more verbose  just putting values directly
    field2 = [OtherModel(), OtherModel()]

    def knockout_fields(self):
        return ['field1', 'field2']

# knockout_objects wouldn't contain proper value of field2 ( it would be equal to [null] 
mymodel_instances = [MyModel(), MyModel()]
knocked_objects = ko_json(mymodel_instances, MyModel().knockout_fields())
```

The issue is that `field2` doesn't serialized with proper value. The result value of `field2` is `{}`, but it suppose to be value json serialized value of `OtherModel` instances.

I have one workaround for that case - we could make json serialization of field2 prior putting to `ko_json`, but it would be great to get universal and reusable solution instead of defining hardcoded names of fields which should be serialized. Thanks in advance.